# Identify notification/alert sound I did not recognise

Tags: macos, audio

My MacBook Pro just made a notification/alert noise that I did not recognise.

I am familiar with all of the sounds that are available as alert sounds under the sounds effects pane in System Preferences, so I am unsure what this was trying to notify me about. I only had Google Chrome open and all tabs I had open did not have any sound-playing components to them (no YouTube, no autoplay ads, etc). It was a longer sound maybe 2–2.5 seconds.

Is there a site that details all the notifications sounds so that I may be able to figure it out?